# Move keys of object to individual properties of child objects, creating an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

The API data looks like this:

```json
{
  "00041335": {
    "productId": "8e786e6b",
    "variantId": "0b43df16"
  },
  "00032183": {
    "productId": "9e780e6d",
    "variantId": "0b48df17"
  }
}
```

I want to make it like this:

```json
[
  {
    "skuId": "00041335",
    "productId": "8e786e6b",
    "variantId": "0b43df16"
  },
  {
    "skuId": "00032183",
    "productId": "9e780e6d",
    "variantId": "0b48df17"
  }
]
```

How to restructure the object? Is `reduce` appropriate or is there a better way?

Comment: Use `Object.keys()` to get the key of the object. Then use that as the value of `Id` in the new object.

Comment: `{ Id1: Object.keys(obj)[0], ...Object.values(obj)[0] }`, or: `const [Id1] = Object.keys(obj); return { Id1, ...obj[Id1] }`

Comment: I’ve edited this post from your details provided at [JavaScript Object -make key as value](/q/71165799/4642212). Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: [`Object.entries`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [destructuring](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [spread](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals). Duplicate target found on [this search page](/search?q=url%3A%22Object%2Fentries%22+url%3A%22Array%2Fmap%22).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way using more efficient destructuring but this did the trick for me:

taking the first object's key value and inserting it into a new object with property id1. then take the object nested in object1 and spread it over the rest of the object.

```
let obj1 ={ "00041335332183": { "Id2": "8e786e6b", "Id3": "0b43df16" } }
let keyValue = Object.keys(obj1);
let newObj = {
  id1: keyValue[0],
  ...obj1[keyValue[0]]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way would to use `Object.keys()`and then you can merge the two objects with the spread operator `(...)`.

```js
const o ={ "00041335332183": { "Id2": "8e786e6b", "Id3": "0b43df16" } }

console.log({ Id1: Object.keys(o)[0], ...Object.values(o)[0] })
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to find the first key of your object, in order to do that you can use [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

`Object.keys(yourobject)` provides your keys in the array format, out of these keys the first index is your ID.

Now you need to create a new object and merge the rest of the data by using the spread operator (...) [Learn from here](https://oprearocks.medium.com/what-do-the-three-dots-mean-in-javascript-bc5749439c9a)

```
let data = { "00041335332183": { "Id2": "8e786e6b", "Id3": "0b43df16" } }

let parsedObject = {id: Object.keys(data)[0], ...data[Object.keys(data)[0]]}

console.log  (parsedObject)
```